# Java regex patterns

Tags: java, regex

I need help with this matter. Look at the following regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+(\\-[A-Za-z]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
```

I want to look for words like this: "home-made", "aaaa-bbb" and not "aaa - bbb", but **not**
"aaa--aa--aaa". Basically, I want the following:

word - hyphen - word.

It is working for everything, except this pattern will pass: "aaa--aaa--aaa" and shouldn't. What regex will work for this pattern?

Comment: Here is an regex test tool: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can can remove the backslash from your expression:

```
"[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+"
```

The following code should work then

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("aaa-bbb");
match = matcher.matches();
```

Note that you can use [`Matcher.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) instead of `Matcher.find()` in order to check the complete string for a match.

If instead you want to look inside a string using `Matcher.find()` you can use the expression

```
"(^|\\s)[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+(\\s|$)"
```

but note that then only words separated by whitespace will be found (i.e. no words like `aaa-bbb.`). To capture also this case you can then use lookbehinds and lookaheads:

```
"(?<![A-Za-z-])[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+(?![A-Za-z-])"
```

which will read

```
(?<![A-Za-z-])        // before the match there must not be and A-Z or -
[A-Za-z]+             // the match itself consists of one or more A-Z
-                     // followed by a -
[A-Za-z]+             // followed by one or more A-Z
(?![A-Za-z-])         // but afterwards not by any A-Z or -
```

An example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![A-Za-z-])[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+(?![A-Za-z-])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("It is home-made.");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());    // => home-made
}
```

Comment: hm ok thank you. If possible, tell me what the backslash did. I'll test now

Comment: it is working, but there is a problem. This shouldnt be considered: aaa-bbb-ccc. And it is actually getting me bbb-ccc and shouldnt

Comment: @user974594 Actually the backslash shouldn't do anything bad in your case. It will work also with your original expression.

Comment: @user974594 And also `aaa-bbb-ccc` fill not match.

Comment: @Howard - Using your lookarounds, wouldn't `(?<!-)[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+(?!-)` be the same thing?

Comment: Oops, no its not the same, since it would match `xxx-yyy` in `-axxx-yyyb-` sorry.

Comment: @Howard, what about the same pattern as in the post, but including this cases: "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd" x times, excluding: "aaaaa--bbbb-c-c-c-".

Comment: @user974594 - Using Howards regex, it could be done `(?<![A-Za-z-])[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+){1,}(?![A-Za-z-])`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can't reproduce the problem mentioned with your expression, if I use single words in the String. As cleared up with the discussion in the comments though, the String s contains a whole sentence to be first tokenised in words and then matched or not.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExp {

        private static void match(String s) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+(\\-[A-Za-z]+)");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                        System.out.println("'" + s + "' match");
                } else {
                        System.out.println("'" + s + "' doesn't match");
                }
        }

        /**
        * @param args
        */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                match(" -home-made");
                match("home-made");
                match("aaaa-bbb");
                match("aaa - bbb");
                match("aaa--aa--aaa");
                match("home--home-home");
        }

}
```

The output is:

```
' -home-made' doesn't match
'home-made' match
'aaaa-bbb' match
'aaa - bbb' doesn't match
'aaa--aa--aaa' doesn't match
'home--home-home' doesn't match
```

Comment: @Howard yes. this one pass for me: home--home-home

Comment: added to my source and DOESN'T match. maybe you're using find() instead of matches(). Try my source.

Comment: Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
        for(int i=0; matcher.find(); i++){ ...

Comment: Now I understand why, I thought the string was representing a single word already.