# Java regex mix two patterns

Tags: java, regex

How can i get this pattern to work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{P}\\p{Z}]");
```

Basically, this will split my String[] sentence by any kind of punctuation character (p{P} or any kind of whitespace (p{Z}). But i want to exclude the following case:

```
(?<![A-Za-z-])[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+){1,}(?![A-Za-z-])
```

pattern explained here: [Java regex patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621821/java-regex-patterns)

which are the hyphened words like this: "aaa-bb", "aaa-bb-cc", "aaa-bb-c-dd". SO, i can i do that?

Comment: `[\\p{P}\\p{Z}^-]` would be my guess

Comment: i dont want to allow this: "--aa", or "bb--c", etc. This two patterns work, i just need to mix the two.

Comment: Well, then... perhaps `[\\p{P}\\p{Z}^(?<![A-Za-z-])[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+){1,}(?![A-Za-z-])]`

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very clear. You want to match any split between words that is not a hyphen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems like you can't merge both expressions, at least as far as I know.

However, maybe you can reformulate your problem.

If, for example, you want to split between words (which can contain hyphens), try this expression:

```
(?>[^\p{L}-]+|-[^\p{L}]+|^-|-$)
```

This should match any sequence of non-letter characters that are not a minus or any minus that is followed my a non-letter character or that is the first or last character in the input.

Using this expression for a split should result in this:

```
input="aaa-bb, aaa-bb-cc, aaa-bb-c-dd,no--match,--foo"
ouput={"aaa-bb","aaa-bb-cc","aaa-bb-c-dd","no","match","","foo"}
```

The regex might need some additional optimization but it is a start.

*Edit*: This expression should get rid of the empty string in the split:

```
(?>[^\p{L}-][^\p{L}]*|-[^\p{L}]+|^-|-$)
```

The first part would now read as "any non-character which is not a minus followed by any number of non-character characters" and should match `.--` as well.

**Edit**: in case you want to match words that could potentially contain hyphens, try this expression:

```
(?>(?<=[^-\p{L}])|^)\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)*(?>(?=[^-\p{L}])|$)
```

This means "any sequence of letters (`\p{L}+`) followed by any number of sequences consisting of one minus and at least one more letters (`(?:-\p{L}+)*+`). That sequence must be preceeded by either the start or anything not a letter or minus (`(?>(?<=[^-\p{L}])|^)`) and  be followed by anything that is not a letter or minus or the end of the input (`(?>(?=[^-\p{L}])|$)`)".

Comment: hm thanks that works. But i need to exclude the cases in which "-" comes first, like: "-a", "-aa-bb" etc..

Comment: @user974594 so `"-aa-bb"` should not be split into `""` and `"aa-bb"`? Could you then provide an example input and expected output? It is not so clear what you're actually trying to achieve.